# xarray chunk dataset PerformanceWarning: Slicing with an out-of-order index is generating more chunks

Tags: bigdata, python-xarray, chunking

I am trying to run a simple calculation based on two big gridded datasets in xarray (around 5 GB altogether, daily data from 1850-2100). I keep running out of memory when I try it this way

```
import xarray as xr

def readin(model):
    observed = xr.open_dataset(var_obs)
    model_sim = xr.open_dataset(var_sim)

    observed = observed.sel(time = slice('1989','2010'))
    model_hist = model_sim.sel(time = slice('1989','2010'))
    model_COR = model_sim

    return(observed, model_hist, model_COR)

def method(model):

    clim_obs = observed.groupby('time.day').mean(dim='time')
    clim_hist = model_hist.groupby('time.day').mean(dim='time')

    diff_scaling = clim_hist-clim_obs
    bc = model_COR.groupby('time.day') - diff_scaling

    bc[var]=bc[var].where(bc[var]>0,0)

    bc = bc.reset_coords('day',drop=True)

observed, model_hist, model_COR = readin('model')
method('model')
```

I tried to chunk the (full)

```
model_COR
```

to split up the memory

```
model_COR.chunk(chunks={'lat': 20, 'lon': 20})
```

or across the time dimension

```
model_COR.chunk(chunks={'time': 8030})
```

but no matter what I tried resulted in

```
PerformanceWarning: Slicing with an out-of-order index is generating xxx times more chunks
```

Which doesn't exactly sound like the outcome I want? Where am I going wrong here? Happy about any help!

Comment: where are you reading the data from? What's the file type? What's the native chunking of the file?

Comment: Oh sorry - it's netcdf files that I read in from a directory. They have the dimensions

time - 91676 
longitude - 84
latitude - 68

Comment: The chunksizes of the original netcdf file are 1, 68, 84 (time, lat, lon)